# Easy way to parse p(x,y) and v(x.y) from files in java

Tags: java, parsing

I am reading in a file in java which looks like this:

```
T(P(p(360,72),p(480,71),p(600,75),p(720,76),p(840,70)),V(v(0,0),v(480,-2),v(1920,-24),v(2400,-26),v(5760,-5),v(6240,-7)))
```

I need to store all the values x and y for each p(x,y) and v(x,y) in an array. I could go through the string character by character, but I was wondering if there is an easier way. Maybe with jSoup or other library?

--update: 
I've implemented it with the pattern matching that was suggested by Paul Rubel, but the problem is that the second number for the v-pairs can be negative. So instead of:

```
   String s = "T(P(p(360,72),p(480,71),p(600,75),p(720,76)" +
                ",p(840,70)),V(v(0,0),v(480,-2),v(1920,-24)" + 
                ",v(2400,-26),v(5760,-5),v(6240,-7)))";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("p\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)");
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
     while (matcher.find()) {
         logger.error(matcher.group(1));
         logger.error(matcher.group(2));
     }
```

I've tried something like:

```
   String s = "T(P(p(360,72),p(480,71),p(600,75),p(720,76)" +
                ",p(840,70)),V(v(0,0),v(480,-2),v(1920,-24)" + 
                ",v(2400,-26),v(5760,-5),v(6240,-7)))";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("p\\((\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\)");
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
     while (matcher.find()) {
         logger.error(matcher.group(1));
         logger.error(matcher.group(2));
     }
```

But now how do I capture the integer. I've also experimented with \p{Punct}, but how do I say this is optional?

Comment: Use regexp and find: "p\((\d+),\d+\)" and "v\((\d+)\.\d+\)" maybe can be used

Comment: nobody wants to write a recursive descent parser anymore? antlr anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression, particularly the [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class' find method.

Repeated calls to find return more matches. So look for `p((\d+),(\d+))` and then again with v.

```
     String s = "T(P(p(360,72),p(480,71),p(600,75),p(720,76)" +
                ",p(840,70)),V(v(0,0),v(480,-2),v(1920,-24)" + 
                ",v(2400,-26),v(5760,-5),v(6240,-7)))";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("p\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)");
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
     while (matcher.find()) {
         logger.error(matcher.group(1));
         logger.error(matcher.group(2));
     }
```

Comment: Works almost perfectly. I think I need to use something else for d+, since the second number of v() can be negative. I've been looking over a list here, but I don't want to mess up the pattern + it is not always there. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html  Maybe adding a punctuation character; how would I make this optional?

Comment: Oh ok, this seems to work and just adds it in the second group: ("p\\((\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\)"). Thanks!